# Set values to component script before attaching it to a gameObject

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine

I'm creating crowd control effects (slow,freeze,stun,snare...) they are all in separate scripts and they are being attached to the player's gameObject when needed. However in case i want to have 2 slows at a time with different values in the script i'm not sure how i can change those. I want to be able to sort of instantiate the script class before adding it to the actual gameObject.

```
Foo someClass = new Foo();
someClass.Duration = 10;
someClass.SlowAmount = 10;
PlayerObject.AddComponent<someClass>();

Foo someClass2 = new Foo();
someClass2.Duration = 1;
someClass2.SlowAmount = 1;
PlayerObject.AddComponent<someClass2>();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly I suggest always using uppercase for your classes and lowercase for variables to easily distinguish them:

```
SomeClass, SomeClass2
```

To answer your question, you could save the class in a variable and then manipulate the values:

```
SomeClass someClass = playerObject.AddComponent<SomeClass>() as SomeClass;
someClass.duration = 10;
someClass.slowAmount = 10;
```

Comment: That's just an example code. Public variables/functions should also start with a capital letter.